# llvm GEP what is the purpose of the first type

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

I'm new to llvm and was wondering in GEP instruction what is the purpose of the first type specified. If I change it to any other type different from `MyType` I get the following error message. So why do I need to explicitly specify it at all and what is its purpose?

`error: explicit pointee type doesn't match operand's pointee type`

```
getelementptr %MyType, %MyType* %7, i64 0, i32 0
```

Comment: http://llvm.org/docs/GetElementPtr.html

Answer (score 0):

There's a general plan to eventually drop the second type, making "a pointer" the only kind of pointer type. LLVM currently contains a few transitional mechanisms that only really make sense in the context of that transition.

When this transition is complete (this year? next? who knows), GEP's result type will depend on its first argument. During this transition, GEP checks that the first and second arguments don't imply different result types.

Comment: @karel Thanks. FYI you can do that kind of change yourself, even on other people's answers, and it's considered good.